# UIImageView Annotation

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am trying to capture an Image from Camera show it on the UIImageView.

After that I have some buttons for e.g. "Paint Brush", "Eraser", "Undo", "Save".

Using Brush I want to mark some items on the image captured.

What is the best way to accomplish the annotation and then save the image.

I am not sure what should be used. Should I use touchesbegan/end etc.. or some other alternative.

Regards,

Nirav

Answer (score 0):

U need to understand Bézier Path Basics.Search it on Google or Apple Documentation.

The UIBezierPath class is an Objective-C wrapper for the path-related features in the Core Graphics framework. You can use this class to define simple shapes, such as ovals and rectangles, as well as complex shapes that incorporate multiple straight and curved line segments.